# Do native speakers of English really ask "What is your mood"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it perfectly natural to ask someone *what is your mood?* when someone wants to know how the person is feeling. If it is not natural at all, as I suspect, then what would they ask instead?

Comment: If you have a friend with a chronic mood disorder, you might ask “How is your mood today?” … as if asking about blood pressure or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not natural to ask "What is your mood?".

A neutral way to ask is: **How are you feeling?**

To confirm that someone is happy: **Are you feeling happy/good?**

If you suspect that a person might not be well or happy: **Are you feeling okay?**

Or just: **Are you okay/alright?**

The latter are most common as a way of checking whether someone who looks ill is okay - or whether someone is injured after falling or being involved in a minor accident.

Comment: Are you in a bad mood? Wow,  you're in a good mood.

Comment: And "what kind of mood are you in?"

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible questions here, namely **Is this idiomatic English?** or **Is the question likely to be asked in a certain context (by a reasonable native speaker)?**

Which are you asking?

Anyhow you can sidestep either question by rewording the specimen as a request.

> Tell me about your mood, if you would.

One problem is that asking questions of the form “What is x?” can be interpreted as asking for definitions.

The [habitual aspect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_aspect) may be expressed by an unmarked, non-progressive form.

To avoid such interpretations and others perhaps, one may use *How is* x + `expression of time`.

The indication of time isn’t necessary, but it can help to make the sense clearer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101408/discussion-on-answer-by-auto-increment-do-native-speakers-of-english-really-ask).